# How to change a control property from a UserControl

Tags: winforms

I have a form named Form1 and 2 UserControl named USC1,USC2. In USC1 i have a Button. Two USCs(USC1,USC2) have been added to Form 1 and the Visible attribute of USC2 is set to false. When i click the button in USC1, how do I get the USC2 to Visible (`USC2.Visible = true`) ?

Picture:
[image]

Comment: Use the **FORM** as the communication method.  Make the first usercontrol raise an event that the form receives.  Upon receipt, now the form can relay the message to the second usercontrol.  An alternative would be to use the Load() or Shown() event of the form to allow a reference to the second usercontrol be passed directly into the first usercontrol; then it could modify the other control directly.

Answer (score 0):

Change the modifier of the `Button` to `public` or expose it via a property. In the form's constructor after `InitializeComponent()`, subscribe to the button's click event:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    USC1.button1.Click += OnButtonClick;
}

private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    USC2.Visible = true;
}
```